# didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath sends NSNotFound iOS6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

Just noticed a crash in my app when a tableview sends delegate event:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and the passed indexPath is `NSNotFound`. Seems to be present in iOS 6.0 and 6.0.1 but fixed in 6.1. I'll post a workaround if I find one.

Seems like it should not send the event with an indexPath containing NSNotFound. Either way its fixed in 6.1. Mainly posting to help others running into this issue

Comment: Did you have a particular question about this behavior?

Comment: I've updated the question, looks like an ios 6 bug

Comment: Can you add an actual answer pointing that out, if indeed it isn't overly localized? It's fine to share knowledge on SO, but you need to stick with the Q&A format.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug in the iOS 6 and 6.0.1 SDK. This doesn't happen in version 6.1. 
A possible workaround is to keep a reference to your cell in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and check for

`indexPath.row == NSNotFound`

Comment: Still happens to me on iOS 6.1

Comment: I concur, still happens.